# D3 How to I get the size of the data after filtering

Tags: javascript, d3.js

If I use this code, for example, to get the odd indexed data values

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data([4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
        .filter(function(d, i) { return i & 1; }))
    .enter().append("div")
        .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

how can I get the size of the data after the filtering operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`selection.size()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-size) for that.

Comment: But don't expect `.enter().size()` to work, because `enter()` selections don't have a size method. After appending you get back a new, normal selection, which has this method. So `.enter().append("div").size()` works fine.

Comment: For enter selections you can use the hacky `[0].length` http://jsfiddle.net/ufx2r5u9/

Comment: How would I modify the code to get the size() into a variable. Sorry new to d3.

Comment: :-) so I have to do the same thing twice? Once to draw and once to get the size? that was my question.

Comment: Or you can apply the filter function to the data, save the result of that and get size and use as data for the selection.

Comment: ok. thats what I wanted to know; if there was somehow a compact way.